# Outlook sorting emails SENT TO by receipient

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In Outlook if I want to sort all the emails sent to john@mail.com, I want to display all of the emails to this person. Currently outlook groups it for me in groups, so I get a batch for the ones sent to:

- john@mail.com
- john@mail.com and mary@mail.com
- anna@mail.com,  john@mail.com and lindsey@mail.com
  etc...

This is really annoying. I tried multiple ways. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I don't know what are you doing wrong but it should be simple enough. Also why don't you try search folder feature ?

Comment: Thats what I thought as well. In search folder do some reason I only part of the emails from this person, even though His address did not Chance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a Custom Search Folder for that? Name it "To john@mail.com", and specify "john@mail.com" in the "Sent To.." box.